# Submit multiple forms that are created in PHP while loop with one button

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am attempting to submit multiple values in separate HTML input fields using one button. These values will be entered into a MySQL table called answers with 3 columns: answerID, questionID and answerBody.

However, each input field is generated using a while loop in a separate PHP function, with the form id being set to 'questions'.

Is it possible to do this?

Here is my code:

survey.php:

```
<?php

    require_once "config/config.php";
    
    //Start the session to grab session details
    session_start();

    //Process data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {

        //Check if fields are empty
        if (empty($_POST["answer"]))
        {
            //State error code
            $answerError = 'Please answer this question.';
        }
        else
        {
            //Set answer
            $answer = $_POST["answer"];
        }

        //Check if error variables have any values assigned
        if (empty($answerError))
        {
            //Prepare database insert
            $sql = "INSERT INTO answers (questionID, username, answerBody) VALUES (?,?,?)";

            //Check if the statement has the connect and sql variables
            if ($statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql))
            {
                //Add variables to the statement
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $paramQuestion, $paramUsername, $paramAnswer);

                //Set the parameter to the answer
                $paramQuestion = $_POST["questionID"];
                $paramUsername = $_SESSION["username"];
                $paramAnswer = $answer;
                

                //Execute statement with entered variable
                if (mysqli_stmt_execute($statement))
                {
                    //Redirect user to success page
                    header("location: thankyou.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }

                //Close statement
                mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
            }
        }

    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<lang='en'>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Survey</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header"><?php head(); ?>
        <form align="right" name="form1" method="post" action="logout.php">
        <p>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["username"] ?>.</p>
        <label class="logoutLblPos">
        <input name="submit2" type="submit" id="submit2" value="Log Out">
        </label>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapperContent">

        <div class="content">
            
            <?php getQuestions($connect); ?>

            <button type="submit" form="questions">Submit</button>

            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"><p><?php if ($_SESSION["username"] == 'admin') { echo footer(); }; ?></p></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in function getQuestions:

```
function getQuestions($connect)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

        if ($result)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $body = $row['questionBody'];
                $questionID = $row['questionID'];


                echo '<div class="entry">
                <div class="questionTitle"><h3>' . $body . '</h3>
                <form id="questions" action="survey.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="questionID" value="' . $questionID . '" />
                <input type="text" name="answer" size="50" />
            func

            </form>
            </div>
            </div>';

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can only submit one form at at time.

Comment: Why do you need to use multiple forms instead of sending the data all in one form?

Comment: @HassanPezeshk because at the moment the way that I have coded the program is that every time I make a new question for this survey that I am creating, it creates a new form for it through the function getQuestions above. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

You can't submit multiple forms via a submit form.
You can either use XHR and send a request per form (which I don't recommend from a performance standpoint) or you can change your `getQuestions` function so that it just adds new inputs to a single existing form. For looping through it easily in your backend, you can use the array format for your input names i.e. `questionID[]` and `answer[]`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have moved `'<form id = "questions" action="survey.php" method="POST">'` to be outside of the while loop so it only creates 1 form. However, when I submit the answers, the submit utton only submits the top answer with the first questionID and not the rest of the answers with their respective questionID. In the database each question also has their own unique questionID automatically generated. Any ideas as to what could be going on?

Comment: @EpicTeddy101 You should change the `name` of your inputs from `questionID` to `questionID[]`